# How to annotate regular function with type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Given the type

```
export interface MyFun {
  (arg: unknown): unknown;
}
```

I can easily annotate arrow function

```
const arrowF: MyFun = arg => {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

but how do I annotate a regular function with the **given** type

```
function regularF(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

The compiler will issue error

> Parameter 'arg' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I'm looking for something like this

```
function<MyFun> regularF(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

which does not work

Update: found related [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063)

Comment: `function regularF(arg: unknown): void { ... }`? See [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Annotating your function like this will have the same effect as using your `MyFun` interface:

```
function regularF(arg: unknown): unknown {
  console.log(arg);
}
```